# Wordpress Kriesi Pagination Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having trouble figuring out this pagination issue on my site. The problem is that page 2 shows the same content as page 1. It's not supposed to do that.

```
<?php
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'baseball-news', 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
                $baseball_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $baseball_loop->have_posts() ) : $baseball_loop->the_post();
                ?>

                    <?php   
                    if ( get_post_type() == 'baseball-news' ) : ?>

                        <?php include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/show-baseball-posts.php' ); ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php kriesi_pagination($baseball_loop->max_num_pages); ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

[This is the site for Kriesi pagination.](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin)

[Site](http://www.botkai.com/baseball/).

Comment: Try a different plugin. I use [PageNavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/), works very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using pagination parameter **paged** in your query. You use it like this:

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'baseball-news', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ,  'paged' => $paged );
```

Comment: Thanks a million! This seems to have done the trick! You've taught me something new today lol.